# Does collecting all the keychains do anything for me?

Tags: kirby-triple-deluxe

As much as I like collecting the keychains for the heck of it - do they actually do anything for me? Collecting the sun stones at least opens levels.

Answer (score -1):

Collecting all the keychains is required for 100% completion